# Rails turn off css for a single partial

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3.2 app.  I use a partial `_invoice_pdf.html.erb` to display an invoice. The same partial is used to create an invoice pdf.  I'm using wicked pdf and it does not include the CSS when creating the pdf.  That's ok - it looks fine.

But, I would like to turn off the CSS when I display the partial on the screen.

Is there a command to not include the css on a particular view (partial)?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Question: when you say partial, do you mean a partial that is included in another view (i.e., `show.html.haml` includes a partial called `_invoice.html.haml`) or are you referring to a view file that is rendered from a controller action (i.e. `show.html.haml`)? I ask because if it's the latter, you could just create an invoice specific layout for that action, one that lacks any CSS includes or declarations (or has a custom CSS set, etc.)

Comment: It is `_invoice_pdf.html.erb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with just HTML and CSS, but with the caveat that the CSS technique is not supported on IE and some mobile browsers. You could get full browser support by changing the CSS to override every individual property being applied to your invoice.

**CSS**

```
#your_invoice {
  all: initial;
  * {
    all: unset;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="your_invoice">
  <%= render "_invoice_pdf.html.erb"%>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally css isn't included in partials, but in the layout or view file that includes the partial. in which case simply either don't include the css in the particular view if appropriate or conditionally exclude it in the layout. Something along the lines of:

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' unless @flag_set_in_controller %>`

Comment: The stylesheet link tag application is in my application.html.erb file which has yield for the other pages.  The view that includes the partial needs the CSS. It's just the partial that doesn't.

Comment: Then you need to modify your css to not affect the partial's contents either by using css scopes and `all: unset` (modern browsers only) or by using something like cssreset or make your css selectors specific enough to not target the contents of the partial.

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize a custom layout and CSS file for this aspect of your application. However, that seems less than ideal or workable based on your comment to Camden's answer (the partial does not need the CSS but the 'outer' elements do).

Otherwise, I think you are looking at conditionally removing the CSS with JavaScript placed in an appropriate block in your partial.

You can remove an external CSS file altogether with a snippet of JS like this:

```
$('link').remove(); // would remove all <link> elements
$('link').not('.myCSSToKeep').remove(); // would remove all <link> elements except for one with class='myCSSToKeep'
```

Should that not be possible for your application, I believe you're down to manually changing styles via their class with jQuery or similar.

```
$('.myClass').css('color', #fff); // and so on
```

If the styles for the PDF could be collected/used from their own CSS file, the first approach should work fairly well ... assuming I'm understanding the requirements correctly :)!